# How do I dynamically call a method that takes an array as parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've a method like:

```
def method (a=[],b=[])
 ...
end
```

I am calling this method with variables like this:

```
method(h[0].values_at("value"), h[1].values_at("value"))
```

where `h[0]` and `h[1]` are hashes. It works fine.

I dont know if `h[1]` is going to be there in the next run, so it's giving me error if hash `h[1]` is not there.

How can I modify it so it makes the call dynamically depending on whether `h[0]`, `h[1]` are there or not, and call the method with the correct number of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I understood your problem right:

```
method(h[0].values_at("value"), 
        h[1] ? h[1].values_at("value") : []
      )
```

Your problem: if `h[1]`does not exist, `h[1].values_at` will raise an exception. So you have to test first, if the value is available. In the code snipllet above I used a ternary operator.

An extended version would be:

```
par2 = []
par2 = h[1].values_at("value") if h[1]

method(h[0].values_at("value"), 
        par2
      )
```

With my solution you don't need the default values in the method definition.

---

In your comment you extended your question.

With four parameters you could use it like this:

```
def method(p1,p2,p3,p4)
  #...
end

method(
    h[0] ? h[0].values_at("value") : [],
    h[1] ? h[1].values_at("value") : [],
    h[2] ? h[2].values_at("value") : [],
    h[3] ? h[3].values_at("value") : [],
  )
```

But I would recommend a more generic version:

```
def method(*pars)
  #pars is an Array with all values (including empty arrays.
  #The next check make only sense, if you need exactly 4 values.
  raise "Expected 4 values, get #{pars.size}"  unless pars.size == 4
end

method( *(h.map{|i|i.values_at("x")})
```

---

And another - probably not so good - idea:

Extend nil (the result of `h[1]` if `h` has not this element) to return `[]` for values_at:

```
class NilClass  
  def values_at(x)
    []
  end
end
```

Comment: above, I used only two params but I've actually 4 paramas in that method. so you mean to say if I do like this `par1 = []
par2 = []
par3 = []
par4 = []
par1 = h[1].values_at("value") if h[0]
par2 = h[1].values_at("value") if h[1]
par3 = h[2].values_at("value") if h[2]
par4 = h[3].values_at("value") if h[3]

method(par1,par2,par3,par4) `   it will take care whether those params are thereor not. i'vent tried yet i'll try now and post the result

Comment: If you have 4 parameters, doing it this way will be a maintenance hassle.  I would suggest `method *(h[0..3].map{|i|i.values_at("x")})` - this expands into however many arguments you have defined, and lets the function defaults take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all for the answers. `method *(h.map{|i|i.values_at("x")})` is working too. But I couldn't understand what does `map` actually doing. Tried to search , but didnt really get the answer. Can someone please point me where `map` is explained properly. Thanks again.

Comment: There are two stars. in `def xx(*args)` it is saying: Give me as much parameters as you want, I store the in the Array `args`. so `xx( 1,2,3 )` results in `[1,2,3]`. The star in the method call makes the opposit. Imagin you have an array `arr = [1,2,3]`. You want to call xx with this parameter list. `xx(arr)` would call xx with one parameter (the array). You may call it with `xx(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2])`. But thats annoying. So you can use `xx(*arr)`. You may find more about this with the keyword [splat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splat)

Comment: Sorry, I'm reading the posts in the wrong order ;). `map` or `collect` loop on the array and call the block for each element of the block. The result of the block is stored in an array. this array is the result of the method `map`. See also http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map

Comment: knut's explanation is correct.  The effect is that the map call generates an array containing the result of calling `values_at` on each element of `h`, then the `*` (or "splat operator")  expands the array into separate arguments to the function.   If `h.size` is smaller than the number of function parameters, the function's default arguments will be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you for explaining this.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do exactly what you ask would be:

```
if h[1]
  method(h[0].values_at("x"), h[1].values_at("x"))
else
  method(h[0].values_at("x"))
end
```

Another idea is to put a default hash in the case where h[1] is nil

```
method(h[0].values_at("x"), (h[1]||{}).values_at("x") )
```

If you are sure `h` never has more than  2 items, you can do:

```
method *(h.map{|i|i.values_at("x")})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ruby On Rails you are able to execute `try` method:

```
method(h[0].values_at("value"), h[1].try(:values_at, 'value') || [])
```

Examples for method `try`:

```
nil.try('[]', :x) # => nil
{:x => 't'}.try('[]', :x) # => 't'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the function signature to accept variable arguments.

```
def foo(*args)
  options = args.extract_options!
  p options
  p args 
end
```

- Invocation without parameters

  ```
  foo()
  {}
  []
  ```
- Invocation with 2 parameters

  ```
  foo(1, 2)
  {}
  [1, 2]
  ```
- Invocation with 3 parameters

  ```
  foo(1, 2, 3)
  {}
  [1, 2, 3]
  ```
- Invocation with 3 parameters and an option hash

  ```
  foo(1, 2, 3, :debug => true)
  {:debug=>true}
  [1, 2, 3]
  ```